# Swapping Endianness In Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, endianness

I need to swap the endianness of some values and just wondered if there was anything available in Objective-C, currently I am swapping the bytes with the CStyle function below (which obviously I can reuse) I just wanted to check there was nothing specific I was missing?

```
float floatFlip(float inFloat) {
    union {
        int intValue;
        float newFloat;
    } inData, outData;

    inData.newFloat = inFloat;
    outData.intValue = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(inData.intValue);
    return(outData.newFloat);
}
```

## EDIT_001

Thanks to the pointers here I have integers sorted, whats the simplest way to swap a float?

```
int myInteger = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(myInteger);
```

(Code above updated)

```
float myFloat = floatFlip(myFloat);
```

gary

Comment: floatFlip() looks fine. I would (personally) write the function name and arguments to be fixed width across the board `Float32 Float32Flip(Float32 inFloat) { union { SInt32 intValue; Float32 newFloat; } inData, outData; ... }`, but I am weird. If you are using C++, I would pass by reference (for the compiler to sanity-check the byte count for you), or (C/objc) pass a pointer since you are primarily interested in a byte swap of the argument, rather than a byte swap of a potentially converted/truncated/reinterpreted value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As well as the APIs already mentioned, there is CoreFoundation/[CFByteOrder.h](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/byte-order_utilities?language=objc).

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `OSSwapInt32()` (or `OSSwapInt16()`, `OSSwapInt64()`, etc.). See [OSByteOrder.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/libkern/libkern/OSByteOrder.h).

Also note that these are non-portable. If you are only converting to big-endian you may want to consider using something like `htonl()`, which is included in the standard library `<arpa/inet.h>`. (Unfortunately, though, there is no standard library for simply swapping back-and-forth.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you found

```
Endian.h    
OSByteOrder.h
```